# Issue with ajax form submission

Tags: ajax, jquery, fancybox

Below is the code that I am using to try to submit a form.. I am getting the following error in firebug:

$("#submit").ajaxForm is not a function

However, the form will submit but go to the test.php page and does not show the success div..

Any help is very much appreciated.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#submit').ajaxForm(function() { 
                $('form#submit').fadeOut(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();}); 
            }); 
        }); 
</script>
<script src="jquery.uniform.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="uniform.default.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<style>
body{
font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
}
p, h1, form, button{border:0; margin:0; padding:0;}
.spacer{clear:both; height:1px;}
/* ----------- My Form ----------- */
.myform{
margin:0 auto;
width:360px;
padding:12px;
}
.error{
margin:0 auto;
width:360px;
padding:12px;
}
.success{
margin:0 auto;
width:360px;
padding:12px;
}



/* ----------- stylized ----------- */
#errored{
border:solid 2px #FAB6C2;
background:#FDE4E1;
font-weight: bold;

}
#successStyle{
border:solid 2px #C0D27B;
background:#E6EFC2;
font-weight: bold;

}
#stylized{
border:solid 2px #EE901F;
background:#FAB766;
}

.LV_valid {
    color:#00CC00;
}

.LV_invalid {
    color:#CC0000;
}

.LV_validation_message{
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:0 0 0 5px;
}

.LV_valid_field,
input.LV_valid_field:hover, 
input.LV_valid_field:active,
textarea.LV_valid_field:hover, 
textarea.LV_valid_field:active,
.fieldWithErrors input.LV_valid_field,
.fieldWithErrors textarea.LV_valid_field {
    border: 1px solid #00CC00;
}

.LV_invalid_field, 
input.LV_invalid_field:hover, 
input.LV_invalid_field:active,
textarea.LV_invalid_field:hover, 
textarea.LV_invalid_field:active,
.fieldWithErrors input.LV_invalid_field,
.fieldWithErrors textarea.LV_invalid_field {
    border: 1px solid #CC0000;
}

</style>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
  body {
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #000;
padding: 40px;
  }
  h1 {
margin-top: 0;
  }
  ul {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
  }
  li {
margin-bottom: 20px;
clear: both;
  }
  label {
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
display: block;
margin-bottom: 3px;
clear: both;
  }
</style>
 </head>
<body>
<form id="submit" method="post" action="test.php"> 
<br>
<div id="stylized" class="myform">
 <ul>
    <li><label>Name:</label><input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="40"/></li>
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
            var name = new LiveValidation('name');
            name.add(Validate.Presence, { failureMessage: ' Name required!' });
            name.add( Validate.Length, { minimum: 2 } );
              </script>
    <li><label>Email:</label><input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="40"/></li>
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
            var email = new LiveValidation('email');
            email.add(Validate.Presence, { failureMessage: '    Email required!' });
            email.add( Validate.Email );
              </script> 
    <li><label>Password:</label><input type="text" id="password" name="password" size="40"/></li>
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
            var password = new LiveValidation('password');
            password.add(Validate.Presence, { failureMessage: ' Password required!' });
            password.add( Validate.Length, { minimum: 6 } );
    </script>   
              <li><label>Verify Password:</label><input type="text" id="verifypassword" name="verifypassword" size="40"/></li>
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
            var verifypassword = new LiveValidation('verifypassword');
            verifypassword.add(Validate.Presence, { failureMessage: '   Password required!' });
            verifypassword.add( Validate.Length, { minimum: 6 } );
            verifypassword.add( Validate.Confirmation, { match: 'password' } );
    </script>   
              <li><label>Company:</label><input type="text" id="custom1" name="custom1" size="40"/></li>
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
            var custom1 = new LiveValidation('custom1');
            custom1.add(Validate.Presence, { failureMessage: '  Company required!' });
              </script>
              <li><label>Country:</label><input type="text" id="custom2" name="custom2" size="40"/></li>
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
            var custom2 = new LiveValidation('custom2');
            custom2.add(Validate.Presence, { failureMessage: '  Country required!' });
              </script> 
              <li><label>Job Title:</label><input type="text" id="custom3" name="custom3" size="40"/></li>
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
            var custom3 = new LiveValidation('custom3');
            custom3.add(Validate.Presence, { failureMessage: '  Job Title required!' });
              </script>  
              <li><label>Telephone:</label><input type="text" id="custom4" name="custom4" size="40"/></li>
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
            var custom4 = new LiveValidation('custom4');
            custom4.add(Validate.Presence, { failureMessage: '  Telephone required!' });
              </script>   
              <li><label>Address:</label><input type="text" id="custom5" name="custom5" size="40"/></li>
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
            var custom5 = new LiveValidation('custom5');
            custom5.add(Validate.Presence, { failureMessage: '  Address required!' });
              </script>       
              <li><label>City:</label><input type="text" id="custom6" name="custom6" size="40"/></li>
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
            var custom6 = new LiveValidation('custom6');
            custom6.add(Validate.Presence, { failureMessage: '  City required!' });
              </script>  
              <li><label>State:</label><input type="text" id="custom7" name="custom7" size="40"/></li>
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
            var custom7 = new LiveValidation('custom7');
            custom7.add(Validate.Presence, { failureMessage: '  State required!' });
              </script>
              <li><label>Postal Code:</label><input type="text" id="custom8" name="custom8" size="40"/></li>
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
            var custom8 = new LiveValidation('custom8');
            custom8.add(Validate.Presence, { failureMessage: '  Postal Code required!' });
              </script> 
              <li><label>What programs and genres are you interested in?</label><input type="text" id="custom9" name="custom9" size="40"/></li>
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
            var custom9 = new LiveValidation('custom9');
            custom9.add(Validate.Presence, { failureMessage: '  Interest required!' });
              </script>     
        <li>
         <label>Terms and Conditions:</label><textarea name="terms" readonly='readonly' cols='40' rows='6'>Terms of Use</textarea>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label> I have read and agree to the terms and conditions.</label><input name="custom10" id="custom10" type="checkbox" />
        </li>
       <li>
         <button type="submit">Register</button>
      </li>
</ul>
</div>
</form>
<div class="success" style="display: none;">
    <div id="successStyle">
    Thank you for submitting your request.<br><br>It will be reviewed shortly and a confirmation e-mail sent to you.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does `jquery.form.js` get loaded? Are you 100% sure?

Comment: Are you sure `jquery.form.js` exists and lives in the same location as `jquery.js`?

Answer (score 0):

The form will submit as non-ajax if the ajax submit doesn't work.

Make sure that you have included the necessary jquery.js and any plugins needed for the function.

Also, triple check the following code for syntax errors and such:

```
$('#submit').ajaxForm(function() { 
    $('form#submit').fadeOut(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();}); 
});
```

I would comment out the `$('form#submit')...` part first.